# App Engine: deploy error

Tags: google-app-engine

I was trying to deploy my service on app engine, It's my 6th service (including the default service). And I got this error after significant amount of time:

```
Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.
```

I deleted all my services from the app engine. And tried again and i got that error again, but this time i was deploying my services in a different order, so the 6th service was different. But the error occurred on 6th service deploy again.

I searched the logs and found this suspicious record:

```
write_gcm: wg_transmit_unique_segment failed.
```

Also from the logs I understood that the service was run, but after some time the system shut it down.

In this condition i can't deploy any services, i get this error.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: potentially related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70365151