# App Engine Flexible: Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying several times to deploy a new version of a service on my app engine flexible instance using the sdk and the command `gcloud app deploy`, but all i get is this error

> "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for
> the app infrastructure to become healthy."

.

I Couldn't found any answer about it on the issue tracker of gcp.

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48193677/8575347) question, he got the same problem, but no one could answered it.

Any guidance will be very helpfull.

Comment: Check your app log for any signs that your app isn't actually healthy. Check that your app properly responds to health checks. Maybe adjust the health checks config in your `app.yaml` if your app takes an unusually long time to start or, better yet, shorted that start time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the gcp team, this particular error was caused because we reached the "In-use IP addresses" quota limit.

They also said that are working on improve the error messages.

> "The engineering team has just created a fix for better quota error
>   details. There is no ETA for when the fix will be released, but I
>   would guess it would be in the next version of gcloud."

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and it took some time to figure out. You can check if this is your issue by going to the "Activity" tab of your project home page. You may have warnings about quota limits and VMs failing to be created. App Engine deployments by default leave previous versions up and running, which might be taking up IP addresses. You can delete previous deployments, and/or request an increase in your IP address quota limit. I requested the limit to be doubled and it was approved within the day.

Answer (score 3):

Over half a year later after Loneck's answer I've got the same error. I guessed it could be anything. This is why I've choosen to delete the project, create a new one in a new zone and deployed it there. Then it worked for me. It might have been any other limitation in the zone that I've choosen at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and solved it by retrying the deploy 3 times.