# Error deploying Laravel+Vue.js project in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I updated composer.json file,created app.yaml and added my configuration to work properly,but i get this error after the command -  gcloud app deploy:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app inf
rastructure to become healthy.
```

In my activity tab in google platform i have this error many times:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App Engine Flexible: Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566318/app-engine-flexible-timed-out-waiting-for-the-app-infrastructure-to-become-heal)

Answer (score 1):

The deployed Google App Engine flexible apps run on GCE virtual machines, meaning, they have an external IP allocated. They are automatically located by geographical region according to the settings in your project, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).

In the Google Cloud Console, go to [IAM & admin > Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) and select Compute Engine API in the Service field and In-use IP adresses in the Metric field.

See if the bar is red in a location, if it is, you reached In-use IP adress [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#ip_addresses) for that region, which is most likely the reason you're getting this error. If you have GCE instances active in said region, either stop, [move](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#move_your_instance) or delete them.

If the error persists, I recommend you to [open a case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases?_ga=2.76962325.-1812584693.1535988484) for support.