# When trying to deploy my nodejs code to gcloud, the url I am deploying to gives a 502 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

First, when trying to deploy my code to the target url in gcloud, the deployment process hangs.

The target url has the suffix appspot.com.

When I ping the target url, I get a request timeout. When I type the target url in my browser, I get a 502 error: server error.

When I deployed the same code to a different test environment in dialogflow, everything seemed to work fine. However when I try deploying again to this url (it is the correct url obtained from the webhook fulfilment url in dialogflow), I get this error:

> Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for
>   the app infrastructure to become healthy.

Everything else, including the node js code and the dialogflow configurations are the same between the two environments I am deploying to, except for the webhook fulfilment url.

Does anyone know what the issue can be narrowed down to? And please let me know if I can include any more useful information.

My guess is that the server is down for that specific URL. One thing to note is that I am using V1 dialogflow.

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566318/app-engine-flexible-timed-out-waiting-for-the-app-infrastructure-to-become-heal) might be the case with you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, it ended up being a firewall issue for that specific url.